# Сохранить время проезда машины (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть две таблицы.

1. `records` - список заявок. Столбцы:
    
   `numcar` - номер машины
   `timepriezd` - ожидаемое время приезда машины (timestamp)
   `pk` - уникальный идентификатор, по умолчанию `NULL`
   `active` - статус проезда машины. (1 - если машина еще не проезжала)
2. `recognized_numbers` - список распознанных номеров. Столбцы:
   `numcar` - номер распознанной машины
   `time` - время, когда машина проехала (`timestamp`)
   `type` - статус проезда (1 - въезд, 2 - выезд)
   `pk` - уникальный идентификатор, `NOT NULL` (`VARCHAR (250)`)

Необходимо составить запрос, который будет делать следующее:
Находить все заявки, у которых статус проезда '1' (`active = '1'`), заменять его на '2';
заменять время предполагаемого проезда, на время фактического проезда.
При этом важно учитывать, что машина может в течении дня и всего времени проехать не один раз.
БД - `MySQL`

Comment: А у вас что-то не получилось? Что именно вы делали и у вас не получилось?

Comment: Я вовсе не могу придумать запрос, который это выполнит.

Comment: Для начала надо словами формулировать какую именно запись из заявок вы хотите найти для конкретной записи из распознанных. Есть статус проезда въезд/выезд какие из записей рассматривать обе или только въезд. Если заявок на один номер несколько какую из них брать к конкретному факту проезда. Что и когда делать со статусом - видимо его надо переводить из active в 0 при первом же проезде по заявки, или нет ?

Comment: Все, у которых статус active = 1. Только те, которые въезжают. Если заявок несколько - та, которая ближе всего к предполагаемому проезда, но не раньше.

Comment: "но не раньше", пусть так конечно, но кажется странным, машина в пробке застряла, задержалась... Хотя конечно в заявке возможно время с запасом стоит

Comment: Ожидаемое время заявки, это время после которого машина может проехать. Раньше ее не пустят. Если машина проехала раньше, значит это другая заявки.

Comment: MySQL не позволяет использовать в подзапросах update (хоть в from, хоть в set) ту же таблицу которую изменяет. А она необходима в условиях, что бы проверить что найдена именно ближайшая к проезду заявка и что данный проезд еще не был учтен под какую нибудь другую заявку. Вердикт: Или использовать внешний ЯП который в цикле пройдет по открытым заявкам и поищет для каждой подходящий проезд или использовать временную таблицу в которую записать одним запросом список того, что надо менять и вторым запросом собственно произвести замену. Второй вариант могу написать в ответе, если подходит

Comment: Нет необходимости. Сейчас сам напишу и укажу в ответе вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Помощь в ответе - [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)

Суть невозможности составить подобный запрос:

> MySQL не позволяет использовать в подзапросах update (хоть в from,
>   хоть в set) ту же таблицу которую изменяет.

В связи с этим пришлось на стороннем ЯП написать скрипт, который выполняет все действия.